# How to mock/stub nested struct function without using interface?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, stub

I am trying to write a UT in go for the first time. I am in a situation where I want to mock a nested structure function. I will describe the scenario with an example code:

```
type C struct {
...
r *R,
...
}

type P struct {
c *C
}

func (p *P) doSomething(...) {
...
p.c.r.Load(...)
...
}
```

Here I am trying to mock p.r.c.Load() function. Any way to achieve this in go?

**Important Note:** We can use interfaces in go to achieve it but I cannot change the business logic.

Thanks in Advance

We can use interfaces in go to achieve it but I cannot change the business logic.

Comment: If you control the package(s) which declare P and C, just patch `r` after `p.c` is constructed. If not, you cannot really do this w/o resorting to ugly hacks like using `unsafe` or monkey patching.

Comment: You cannot. Dead simple. You should not either. Inject a R with a suitable implementation.